# Save a bitmap at same folder as the original with a set name

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a program that loads a file by input in console, convert the picture into greyscale, negative and blurred. Then I want to make copys of the converted picture in the same folder as the original with extra text at the filename (ex: picture_negative.jpg). My problem is that i can't figure out how i save the pictures in the save folder with the extra text.

This is my first month with programming so im not very experienced.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap picture;
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Write the file you want to edit ");
                picture = new Bitmap(Console.ReadLine=                 
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No picture choosen");
                return;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
                return;
            }

            ConvertAlgoritms.ConvertAlgoritms.MakePictureGreyScale(picture);
            ConvertAlgoritms.ConvertAlgoritms.MakePictureNegative(picture);
            ConvertAlgoritms.ConvertAlgoritms.MakePictureBlurred(picture);
        }
```

Example of the class

```cs
 public class ConvertAlgoritms
    {
        public static Bitmap MakePictureGreyScale(Bitmap originalPicture)
        {
            Bitmap newPicture = new Bitmap(originalPicture);

            int x, y;
            for (x = 0; x < newPicture.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < newPicture.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixel = newPicture.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int r = pixel.R;
                    int g = pixel.G;
                    int b = pixel.B;
                    int greyScale = (r + g + b) / 3;
                    newPicture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(greyScale, greyScale, greyScale));
                }
            }
            return newPicture;
        }
}
```

Comment: [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path) might be your friend. With methods like `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `GetExtension`, you can probably play around to get the correct new filename you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Bitmap.Save()`.

First, you must save the entered file name in the console into a variable.

Then, you can append a string to this name before the extension.

Example:

```
Console.Write("Write the file you want to edit ");
Filename = Console.ReadLine();
picture = new Bitmap(Filename);

string NewFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Filename)
                   + StrToAppend
                   + Path.GetExtension(Filename);

picture.Save(Newfilename, picture.RawFormat);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pick up the returned image e.g.:

```
var greyscalePicture = ConvertAlgoritms.ConvertAlgoritms.MakePictureGreyScale(picture);
```

Then you can just save it:

```
greyscalePicture.Save("Fancynewfilename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This assumes that your file format is JPEG.
To generate the new filename you need to keep a reference to the old one.

```
var originalFilename = Console.ReadLine();
var picture = new Bitmap(originalFilename);
```

Then you can build the filenames using the `Path` class as @Corak suggests.